# I want to save to CORE DATA, but I keep getting a 'An NSManagedObject of class 'Reminder' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

#### What am I doing wrong?

This is what I want to save:

```
//To save in Core Data
let my_reminder = Reminder(context: CoreDataService.context)
my_reminder.name = "a title"
my_reminder.date = "a date"
my_reminder.content = "some text"
CoreDataService.saveContext() //a class that handles core data
```

This is my CoreDataService Class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataService {
    
    static var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    
    private init(){}
    
    // MARK: - Core Data stack
    static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "project_name")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    static func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Error message:**

```
An NSManagedObject of class 'Reminder' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.
```

I Keep getting the error time and time again, do I need to update the **plist**? I Checked everything and still nothing seems to work

(I'm using **Swift 4** and **XCODE 9** by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't remember the username, but somebody recomended I changed line:

```
let my_reminder = Reminder(context: CoreDataService.context)
```

to something like:

```
if let my_reminder = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Reminder", into: CoreDataService.context) as? Reminder {
            print("Start saving")
            my_reminder.name = "a title"
            my_reminder.date = "a date"
            my_reminder.content = "some text"
            CoreDataService.saveContext()
        }
```

also, I had something wrong in my CoreDataService class, the **NSPersistentContainer** doesn't recieve the name of the of the project, but rather the name of the **XCDataModeld** file, which tends to be the same, but wasn't in my case:

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
```